# java .split() method gives arrays of different lengths

Tags: java, arrays, split

I am reading lines from a tsv file, and then trying to delimit them by `words = array.split("\t")`

words is an array that i have already initiated by `String[] words = {"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"}` so it has a fixed length of 6. However, words[i] can have a different length of words[j]. I absolutely want words to have its length fixed to 6. Why is that happening and how do i fix this?

Tried `for(int i=0; i<x; i++){ String[] words = new String[6] }`

Comment: When you assign the result of the split to `words` whatever was previously assigned to `words` is discarded. It's irrelevant how big the array was beforehand. How many tab separated columns are in your lines? Do you want to limit the split to 6?

Comment: there are 6 columns, but each line doesn't necessarily mean that has 6 values that i can read.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? Every time you execute `words = array.split("\t");` words will have a fresh array assigned to it, which will have length of however many columns are in the line. Also, renaming `array` to `line` would be less confusing.

Comment: is there a way to make the array fixed to a size of 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting a string, taking maximum 6 values, and filling an array with the `"0"` string if there are too few values.

```
        String[] defaultWords = {"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"};
        int fixedSize = defaultWords.length;
        String[] words = new String[fixedSize];

        // reading
        String str = "1\t2\t3";
        String[] tmpWords = str.split("\t");
        System.arraycopy(defaultWords, 0, words, 0, fixedSize);
        System.arraycopy(tmpWords, 0, words, 0, Math.min(fixedSize, tmpWords.length));

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

String.split has an override you can use to limit the output. It will grab the first n number of the string and then stop.

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int)):

> **The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied** and therefore affects the length of the resulting array.
>
> - If the limit is positive then the pattern will be applied at most limit - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than limit, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter.
> - If the limit is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.
> - If the limit is negative then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length.

Here's an example

```
String[] splitWithoutLimit = "Column1,Column2,Column3".split(",")

// splitWithoutLimit will contain the following values:
// { "Column1", "Column2", "Column3" }

String[] splitWithLimit = "Column1,Column2,Column3".split(",", 2)

// splitWithLimit will contain the following values:
// { "Column1", "Column2,Column3" }
```

Comment: It doesn't "stop" consuming the input at the given limit (ie discard the extra elements), it just piles all the remaining input into one element, which I expect is not what OP wants.